# DocuSign Decline Reasons Radio button with Textbox

Tags: docusignapi

I need to have radio button list with few options with an additional textbox in docusign decline reasons.

I'm able to create a radio button list by updating the signing resources with

```
<data name="DocuSign_DeclineReasons">800=Decline Reason 1;900=Decline Reason 2;1000=Decline Reason 3</data>
```

[Docusign Sample UI modified](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0SVY.png)

However adding any html tags is not working in it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add html related attributes in `signing resource file`. HTML tags work only on `email resource file`.

Comment: Thanks, however is there a way to capture and option and additional information with it in Decline reason.

Comment: If any signer selects `Decline` option then you can retrieve this reason either using `DocuSign API` or `DocuSign connect`. `DocuSign Connect` is a recommended approach as it does not involve polling, instead `DocuSign Connect` works on subscribe-publish model.